# Replace word (MRAW) in a Forest plot

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I have run a metanalysis using the meta package and created the following forest plot. I do not know what is MRAW stands for? I want to replace the word MRAW How can I do that?

I have used the following code to create the forest plot

```
forest(Mean_LYSHOLM_PRE,fixed = FALSE, random = TRUE, overall= FALSE, col.random = "blue", prediction = TRUE, pooled.events = TRUE, xlab = "Preoperative Lysholm Scores",fs.xlab = 14,weight.study = "random", col.study = "black", col.square = "red",col.square.lines = "black", col.diamond = "black",hetstat = TRUE, overall.hetstat = FALSE, hetlab = "Heterogeneity",resid.hetstat = FALSE, print.I2 = TRUE, print.tau = TRUE)
```

[image]